# Антивирус Касперского определяет фавикон моего сайта как вредоносный элемент и блокирует сайт. Как это исправить?

Tags: html, url, favicon

Пишу в браузере url сайта, при переходе блокирует как вредоносное по. Фавикон есть расширение ico и размер соответствует требованиям. Браузер добавляет запрос favicon.ico , а в адресной строке пишет url/#

Отчёт kaspersky такой:

Событие: Переход остановлен
<...>
Тип: Вредоносная ссылка
Название: https://m7y.ru/favicon.ico
Точность: Точно
Степень угрозы: Высокая
Тип объекта: Веб-страница
Имя объекта: favicon.ico
Путь к объекту: https://m7y.ru
Причина: Облачная защита

Как исправить проблему? Чтоб антивирус не определял как вредоносное ПО фавикон и сайт ?

Comment: Отправьте им ссылку на свой сайт и спросите, что это такое. А паралельно можно снести этот "антивирус" толку с него все равно мало.

Comment: Самое легкое решение этой проблемы - удалить антивирус

Comment: Обратилась в их тп. помогло.